# Access the attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access the value of an attribute defined in the checkbox.
The code of defining the checkbox is :

```
<input id="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="item" class="row" statusid="10" value="175627">
```

This peice of code is inside a phtml file .

Now in my JS file,I want to access the attribute value for statusid i.e 10.
How can I achieve this ?

Please refer below image for clear understanding.
[image]

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute):

```
document.getElementById("checkboxes").getAttribute("statusid")
```

**[-- View Demo --](http://jsfiddle.net/kqhkwLpt/)**

Comment: Dangit, beat me to it. +1 :P

Comment: Hi, this has worked file.
Thanks for it .

But I am facing one issue.
There are multiple check-boxes in my table which have diffrent status-id's associated with them.
By using the above code, I am only getting the value of 1st checkbox.


How can I get the values of all the checkboxes?

Comment: @Daffy You should have only one ID per element. Therefore give them all different IDs

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var input = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
var statusID = input.getAttribute("statusid");
```

to get the attribute.

Comment: Hi, this also had worked fine.
Thanks for it .

But I am facing one issue.
There are multiple check-boxes in my table which have diffrent status-id's associated with them.
By using the above code, I am only getting the value of 1st checkbox.


How can I get the values of all the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the statusid attribute:

```
Using jQuery:
$("#checkboxes").attr('statusid');

Pure Javascript:
document.getElementById('checkboxes').getAttribute('statusid');
```

If you want to get the value of input element that statusid attribute has value of 10 (will return 175627 for your example):

```
Using jQuery:
$("input[statusid='10']").val(); 

Pure Javascript:
document.querySelector("input[statusid='10']").value;
```